# Can I integrate third-party WAF engine to AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I did some reading and found that you can only run AWS WAF attached to your AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). I have a partner WAF solution running as VM, can I hook a third-party WAF solution to AWS ALB?

Few other details:

- AWS ALB is configured to do SSL offloading. Partner WAF VM requires plain HTTP traffic.
- I don't want to introduce a bump in the wire. I wanted easy / low-touch integration where all the traffic from AWS ALB should be inspected by partner WAF VM.

Any suggestion here will be helpful.

Comment: No that's not possible. You would have to have the load balancer send all traffic to your WAF VM, and then somehow have the WAF VM distribute the traffic across your group of servers.